# Can I use result (latent variables) from CFA as input to ANOVA (dependant variable)?

Tags: anova, confirmatory-factor

I am currently writing a paper. And I am not sure if I can use latent variable defined through CFA, as a dependent variable in ANOVA. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

just a pointer to two articles that may help/inspire you: A recent paper by Helm et al. that uses SEM and ANOVA ([here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10705511.2022.2033977)) and a paper on factor score regression, in case you want to use the factor scores in the ANOCA ([here](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0013164415607618)).

Hope that helps

Stefan